# Check if terms have leading + except the first one

Tags: java, regex

I have the following example search string:

```
term1 +term2 +term3
```

My question would be how can I check if the first term does not have a leading `+`and the other ones have a leading `+`.

Is there a regex to do that?

Comment: There probably is. But you should provide your own attempt first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String pattern = "\\+.*";
    String input = "paramA +paramB";
    String input2 = "+paramA +paramB";

    Assert.assertFalse(input.matches(pattern));  // False
    Assert.assertTrue(input2.matches(pattern));  // True
```